# Understanding UNIX Pipes and File Descriptors

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am new to UNIX pipe communication and in need of some help here understanding this. I need to create pipes and fork off child process that communicate with the parent process via these pipes. My questions are

a) Why a pipe per child process?

b) What are file descriptors really, and do I need to create one per pipe?

c) What do the StdIn and StdOut to do with all this?

Comment: Lots of questions! Perhaps split up each one? A better place to try might be unix.stackexchange.com for UNIX/linux questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why a pipe per child process?

Because a single pipe has only two endpoints. If you tried to share a single pipe among all the children, you wouldn't know which child process generated a given piece of output.

> What are file descriptors really?

Entries in the table of open files held by the operating system.

> Do I need to create one [file descriptor] per pipe?

Any process which has any file-like object open, including either end of a pipe, needs to have a file descriptor through which it can communicate with that file-like object. Indeed, having an entry in the file descriptor table pointing to that file is exactly what having a file open *is*.

> What do stdin and stdout have to do with this?

stdin is entry 0 in the file descriptor table; stdout is entry 1. If the processes you're launching read and write their data to file descriptors 0 and 1, that may be where you want your pipes attached.